# Swift CoreData: Unable to cast annotation.view as Pin

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on the CoreData project on Udacity and am having some difficulty casting annotation.view as Pin. The purpose of casting it as Pin would allow me to push Pin into the next VC to retrieve its respective photos via CoreData filtered by predicate. My codes as such:

```
// Pin Model
import Foundation
import CoreData
import MapKit

public class Pin: NSManagedObject, MKAnnotation {

convenience init(lat: Double, long: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    if let ent = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Pin", in: context) {
        self.init(entity: ent, insertInto: context)
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
    } else {
        fatalError("Unable to find Entity name!")
    }
}

public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    get {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat as Double, longitude: long as Double)
    }

    set {
        lat = newValue.latitude
        long = newValue.longitude
    }
}
}

//MapViewController
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseId = "pin"

    let pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

    pinView.animatesDrop = true
    pinView.isSelected = true

    return pinView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let pin = view.annotation as! Pin
    mapView.deselectAnnotation(pin, animated: false)
    viewPin(pin)
}

func viewPin(_ pin: Pin) {
    let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionVC") as! PhotoAlbumCollectionViewController
    controller.pin = pin
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

The error occurs at view.annotation as! Pin where it indicates that

> Could not cast value of type 'NSKVONotifying_MKPointAnnotation'
>   (0x60800010d140) to 'VirtualTouristJR.Pin' (0x10f07b8b0).

Could anyone pls advice, thanks!

EDIT: Code for adding Pin

```
func addAnnotation(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
        let touchCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = touchCoordinate

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        print(touchCoordinate)

        let stack = delegate.stack
        addedPin = Pin(lat: touchCoordinate.latitude, long: touchCoordinate.longitude, context: (stack?.context)! )
        do {
            try stack?.saveContext()
        } catch {
            print("Error while saving.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New Answer

You are creating *MKPointAnnotations* in `addAnnotation`, not *Pins*! Therefore, you will also get MKPointAnnotations and not Pins in `mapView(_:didSelect:)`.

You could change your code to:

```
func addAnnotation(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
        let touchCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

        print(touchCoordinate)

        let stack = delegate.stack
        let addedPin = Pin(lat: touchCoordinate.latitude, long: touchCoordinate.longitude, context: (stack?.context)! )
        do {
            try stack?.saveContext()
            mapView.addAnnotation(addedPin)
        } catch {
            print("Error while saving.")
        }
    }
}
```

I removed all the MKPointAnnotation stuff and added the pin as an annotation to the map. You'll surely have to cross-check if the app still works as expected, since I do not know the whole project.

---

### Old Answer

I think I got the same problem some years ago :-)
At that time, the problem was that there are some built-in-Annotations (like the current location) which are therefore implemented as MKPointAnnotation and not as your custom Pin-class. 
You should try to use an `as?` cast to check whether it's a Pin or sth. else:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let pin = view.annotation as? Pin {
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(pin, animated: false)
        viewPin(pin)
    } else {
        print ("Oops, got something unwanted") // Maybe add breakpoint here to check.
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted this method before, but it gave me the print statement in the else statement. I can't seem to figure out how to overcome this problem as I would need the 'Pin' to deal with my predicate statement in fetchedResultsController

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you add the annotations to the MKMapView?

Comment: OK, I think I found a solution to your problem, please re-check my edited anser.

Comment: It works when i add the pin as a newly added pin now. Meaning to say when I drop a new pin, it successfully takes me to the newVC. But upon restarting the app and tapping on the existing pins, it prints the 'opps' statement...

Comment: Hi there, i solved, it seems that the fetchAllPins were still added like how i added previously (MKPointAnnotations). Once i changed all to Pins it works now. Thanks!